# Hyperlink entire Column in Excel till the Text "Total"

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to Hyperlink entire column "B" based on the contents of that cell until it reaches the text "Total" in Column A. I am using the below code, I tried If condition and Do loop, however i am not getting the result.

Just to mention there is  a blank rows after each row, and it can be dynamic as it based on the data.

Any help appreciated.

```
Private Sub Hyperlink_1()

Dim i
Dim file As String
Dim path As String
Dim file1

i = 6

While Range("B" & i).Value + "" <> ""

path = Range("C3").Value & Application.PathSeparator
file = Dir$(path & Range("B" & i).Value & ".*")
file1 = path & file

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
Anchor:=Range("B" & i).Offset(, 0), _
Address:=file1
Range("B" & i).Offset(, 0).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
Range("B" & i).Offset(, 0).Font.Color = -10477568

i = i + 1

Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Private Sub Hyperlink_1()

Dim I
Dim File As String
Dim Path As String
Dim File1
Dim rTot As Range

    Set rTot = Range("A:A").Find("Total")
    If Not rTot Is Nothing Then
        Path = Range("C3") & Application.PathSeparator
        For I = 6 To rTot.Row - 1
            If Range("B" & I) <> "" Then
                File = Dir$(Path & Range("B" & I) & ".*")
                If File <> "" Then
                    File1 = Path & File
                    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
                        Anchor:=Range("B" & I), _
                        Address:=File1
                        Range("B" & I).Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
                        Range("B" & I).Font.Color = -10477568
                End If
            End If
        Next I
    Else
        MsgBox "Total not found", vbCritical, "CRITICAL"
    End If

End Sub
```